# Parsing awkward JSON format in C#

Tags: c#, json

A scenario is modelled using a `DSML` which is developed at my university. Now this can be exported to a `JSON` format, an example looks like this:

```
{
    "_entries": [
        "g0"
    ],
    "_flow": {
        "g3": {
            "_expr": [
                {
                    "word_": "player",
                    "next_": [
                        {
                            "word_": "rebukes",
                            "next_": [
                                {
                                    "word_": "jack"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "g4": {
            "_expr": [
                {
                    "word_": "player",
                    "next_": [
                        {
                            "word_": "supports",
                            "next_": [
                                {
                                    "word_": "jack"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "g2": {
            "_type": "cho",
            "_paths": [
                "g3",
                "g4"
            ]
        },
        "g1": {
            "_next": "g2",
            "_expr": [
                {
                    "word_": "player",
                    "next_": [
                        {
                            "word_": "goes to",
                            "next_": [
                                {
                                    "word_": "jack"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "g0": {
            "_next": "g1",
            "_expr": [
                {
                    "word_": "jack",
                    "next_": [
                        {
                            "word_": "bullies",
                            "next_": [
                                {
                                    "word_": "jeff"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So basically there can be more than one flow declared in the JSON. (every entry points to the start of a new flow, just take a look at it, it's fairly easy to *read and understand* it).

Now I am importing this JSON file in `Unity3D` where I want to parse this using `C#` and base the game on what is declared in this JSON file. I am quite new to using Unity, C# and JSON and this JSON format is completely different than what most tutorials explain. I cannot get my head around this one.

Comment: are you interested in all the contents in this JSON response, or you just want some specific string(s)?

Comment: How is this json different? I see objects and arrays and validates nice on http://jsonlint.com/ What is your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could model this with the following data structure:

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember(Name = "_entries")]
    public string[] Entries { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "_flow")]
    public IDictionary<string, Flow> Flow { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Flow
{
    [DataMember(Name = "_expr")]
    public Expression[] Expressions { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Expression
{
    [DataMember(Name = "word_")]
    public string Word { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "next_")]
    public Expression[] Next { get; set; }
}
```

and then using [`JSON.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/json) easily deserialize the JSON string to this structure:

```
string json = ...
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's the first time I use JSON and I couldn't figure it out by following stuff online